# Matlab: reading in .csv files, performing a command, and exporting data

Tags: excel, matlab, file, csv, directory

I want to read in a bunch of different .csv files from a folder, average the 9th column of each individual one (starting at the 2nd row because I want to exclude the headers), and then output the averages into a new .csv file as a single column list. I have tried some code so far, but Matlab just says it is busy and never reads or outputs anything. Any advice on where to go next? Thanks!

```
function csv_write_2()
folder   = 'C:\Users\Brent\Desktop\MCGOUGH\2017-07-12_bov_da_medmen-l_01\vic-2d_data';
csvFiles = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.csv'));
numfiles = length(csvFiles);
average  = zeros(1, numfiles);
for k = 1:numfiles
  M = csvread(fullfile(folder, csvFiles(k).name),1,0);
  average(k) = mean(M(:,9));
end
csvwrite(fullfile(folder, 'output.csv'), average);
end
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your function using the debugger to see what's causing the problem?

Comment: I have but when I insert a breakpoint to try to see if it is looping through properly, the code runs for a very long period of time and won't let me click on the variable created to see if it did what I want it to do.

Comment: How big are the CSVs?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Presumably it's freezing because you have very big csv files?? In which case, since you're only after the 9th column, you might as well discard the first 8 directly from your csvread. If you knew how many rows you have you could focus on just that column by defining a range as well ... but alas, I remember you mentioning in the previous question that the number of rows is not constant; unfortunately matlab does not provide syntax to choose until there's no more data, and it throws an error if you exceed the number of available rows.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tasos. Yes, the CSVs are large (150,000+ rows x 15 columns) as well as dynamic. If I'm interpreting correctly, I think I can make it so that matlab only reads the matrix starting at the column I am interested in, but I cannot end the column offset (i.e. I would like for it to only have to read the 9th) because I cannot provide row offsets to finish the format of M = csvread(filename,R1,C1,[R1 C1 R2 C2]). This is a little frustrating!

Comment: Now I'm getting a dlmwrite error "number of header columns is greater than number of columns in file" after it runs for 45 minutes or so :(

Comment: @amcgough hi (Anna, was it?). Just letting you know people don't automatically receive notifications when you reply unless you 'tag' them using the '@ + username' tag (but the author of the question / answer always gets notified regardless). Only reason I saw this is because I remembered and was curious to see what happened in the end :p

Comment: also in general, you might want to mark answers to your (previous) questions as accepted if they resolve the specific issue relating to the question, so that they're removed from the list of unanswered questions for future googlers :)

Comment: as for the error ... not sure :/ ... Is that the case in reality? I.e. if you open this file in excel, does the file have more column 'headers / names' than it does 'number' columns?

Comment: the only other thing I would suggest is, since you're dealing with a relatively specialised scenario, you may consider using "low-level" file-reading facilities, and 'tokenize' manually, collecting only the data you want for processing. Also, if by "dynamic" you mean that data keeps getting appended to the file in _real_ time, then this method would make more sense _anyway_. I can give you an example of how you might do that if you'd like.

Answer (score -1):

Two suggestions:

1) Use the "Import Data" GUI button to generate the script for importing from the CSV.  This is in the "Home" tab.  You'll click it, then select the data you want to import, the format you want it imported as, etc.  Then click the down arrow under "Import Selection" and click "Generate Function".  You can then modify this function as needed, and call it in a loop to loop over your various CSV files.  This way you'll know you've got the importing part written correctly.

2) Use [xlsread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) instead.  This does take longer to run, but is MUCH more intuitive an easy to use.  There's also xlswrite, which I haven't used, but I assume is similarly easy.